# property 'filter' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular, filter, angular5

Can anyone tell me why property filter doesn't work here ?

```js
   delete(user: User): void {
       
    this.userService.deleteUser(user)
      .subscribe( data => {
        this.user = this.user.filter(u => u !== user);
      })
```

knowing that user is declared as an interface and not as a class

Comment: shouldn't be data.filter?

Comment: And User is not an Array, or User object doesn't have method called "filter" in it.
So it doesn't work

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work , and data is taking this.entity so it s the same thing i guess

Comment: oups it s because user was not declared as a list =>   user: User[];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved :

```js
user: User[];
```